# SQL Left Join Query for more column

Tags: sql

I wish to join the following two tables

```
Table_1_CODE

Code    Desc
LC01    Karachi
LC02    Hyderabad
DP01    Account
DP02    Marketing
SH01    Night
SH02    Day


Table_2_DETAILS 

Col_1   Col_2   Col_3   Col_4
Mumtaz  LC01    DP02    SH01
Sajid   LC02    DP01    SH02
Imtiaz  LC01    DP02    SH02
```

**The output i am looking for is**

```
Name    Loc        Dept       Shift
Mumtaz  Karachi    Marketing  Night
Sajid   Hyderabad  Account    Day
Imtiaz  Karachi    Marketing  Day
```

I wish to do this using SQL

Comment: Join Table_1_Code several times.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query:

```
SELECT col_1, t11.description, t12.description, t13.description
FROM Table_2_DETAILS t2 INNER JOIN Table_1_Code t11 
ON t11.code = t2.Col_2 
INNER JOIN Table_1_Code t12
ON t12.code = t2.col_3
INNER JOIN Table_1_Code t13
ON t13.code = t2.col_4;
```

I haven't run the query, so if any issue please comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want. You have to join Table 1 multiple times on different columns.

```
SELECT Col_1 AS 'Name',a.[Desc] AS 'Loc',b.[Desc] AS 'Dept',c.[Desc] AS 
'Shift'
FROM Table_2
   JOIN Table_1 a ON Table_2.Col_2 = a.Code
   JOIN Table_1 b ON Table_2.Col_3 = b.Code
   JOIN Table_1 c ON Table_2.Col_4 = c.Code 

ORDER BY c.[Desc] DESC
GO
```

Comment: Your welcome. I just noticed I had the 3rd column named the same as the 1st. I updated the query.